# Changing values on aspx from thread

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently trying to do something with threads and asp and it's giving me a lot of headaches.

The problems is that i have an aspx and through a delegate invoked on a thread, i want to change page title, and some controls values. Here is the code.

```
namespace back
{
    public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        public delegate void ElDelegado();

        public ElDelegado d;


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Session.Contents.Count == 0)
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

            d = new ElDelegado(ChangeText);

            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ElThread));
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();


        }

        public void Salir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session.RemoveAll();
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }

        public void ElThread()
        {
            d();
        }

        public void ChangeText()
        {
            this.Page.Title = "El título";
            lbl.Text = "El texto";
        }
    }
}
```

When debugging, i can see that Title's value changes, but i don't see the change on UI.

Comment: I think changes will reflect once page gets postback.

Comment: You can't do that.  The page will only get updated as part of the postpback. Why do you need a thread?

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to first understand ASP.net Page Life cycle.

Following is problem area.

1. Before you change title you page_load event get completed and response already sent to client. Once response sent to client you can not do anything.
2. If you want to update page title based on some calculation better look for option in AJAX call.
3. In your code if you want thread to change title and it display in page title of browser you have to wait for thread to finish its work.

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if(Session.Contents.Count == 0)
           Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

       d = new ElDelegado(ChangeText);

       Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ElThread));
       t.IsBackground = true;
       t.Start();
       t.Join();

   }
   ```